# how to associate .pde with processing

Tags: file-association

On Ubuntu 14.04 in order to click on a PDE file and associate processing.

Clicking launches gedit, the default for text files.
right clicking on the icon shows the different programs that could be executed, and clicking additional lists a lot more, but not processing.

Processing is at this point installed at:

```
/opt/processing-3.06b/
```

so I added that to the path, but that did not add it to the list of applications.

There does not appear to be any way to execute an arbitrary command.

Comment: You need a desktop file for the `processing` executable and a little bit more. And that's, why I need the mimetype of your pde file. Run `mimetype your.pde`

Comment: mimetime is text/plain

Comment: What's the binary/script which you start or can I have a download link?

Comment: processing.org is the download.  To run the program /path/processing.

Comment: Have you used my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need a desktop file:

1. Create a desktop file

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/processing.desktop
   ```
2. Add the following entries

   Replace the attribute for `Path` with a valid icon path and note the `%f`. That's necessary to open a file in your file manager with this desktop file.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Processing
   Icon=/opt/processing-3.06b/processing.png
   Exec=/opt/processing-3.06b/processing %f
   Comment=Processing is a flexible software sketchbook
   Categories=Development;
   Terminal=false
   StartupWMClass=Processing
   MimeType=text/plain;
   ```
3. Open your file manager and navigate to a PDE file. Open the <kbd>Properties</kbd> dialog and the tab <kbd>Open With</kbd>. Search the entry <kbd>Processing</kbd> in the list and use the button <kbd>Set as default</kbd>

   [image]